# How to create data frame of random floating point numbers with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, random

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,253,size=(253, 830)), columns=list_cols)
```

I used this for getting random integers but i needed floating point numbers instead. Any idea how?

Comment: Use : `np.random.randint(0,253,size=(253, 830)).astype(float)`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. it worked.

Answer (score 9):

`randint` generates random integers, use `rand` to get random numbers between 0 and 1. You can then multply that by the maximum value you want. (which I guess is 254 rather than 253).

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(253, 830) * 254, columns=list_cols)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numpy.random.uniform` to create dataframe with floating numbers between a and b.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(253, 830)), columns=list_cols)
```

for further information refer to [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) .

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


## Let's create 5000 rows and 4 different columns
arr_random = np.random.default_rng().uniform(low=5,high=10,size=[5000,4])
arr_random

## Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(arr_random, columns=["A","B","C","D"])
```